# How would I get rid of all of the spaces and brackets once the final 5 usernames have been printed?

Tags: python

```
#This is a program that generates usernames    
from random import randint 
usernames=[]
for i in range (5): 
     firstname=input("What is your first name?") 
     lastname=input("What is your last name?") 
     print("Your username is")
     a=(str(randint(0,9)))+""+lastname[0:3].lower()+""+firstname[0].upper()+""+str((len)(lastname))
     print(a)
     usernames.append(a)
print(usernames)
```

I want there to be only a single space between each username that is printed at the end. Right now this is the outcome: ['6kK1', '8kK1', '0kK1', '3kK1', '7kK1']. How do I get rid of the brackets and commas and speech marks so that there is only one space between each of the usernames. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [string.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method

```
' '.join(usernames)
```

Example:

```
In [5]: usernames = ['6kK1', '8kK1', '0kK1', '3kK1', '7kK1']

In [6]: print(' '.join(usernames))
6kK1 8kK1 0kK1 3kK1 7kK1
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot.